# I am trying to sort a linked list in descending order

Tags: python

Can you please help me, i am trying to sort the linked lists according to the documentation in the add function but i am getting an error which says:
f.add('b', 2)
File "", line 69, in add
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
how can i avoid this?
Thankyou.

```
class Frequency(object):
    """

    Stores a letter:frequency pair.

    >>> f = Frequency('c', 2)
    >>> f.letter
    'c'
    >>> f.frequency
    2
    >>> f
    {c: 2}
    """
    def __init__(self, letter, frequency):
        self.letter = letter
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{%s: %d}' % (self.letter, self.frequency)

class SortedFrequencyList(object):
    """
    Stores a collection of Frequency objects as a sorted linked list.
    Items are sorted from the highest frequency to the lowest.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, letter, frequency):
        """
        Adds the given `letter`:`frequency` combination as a Frequency object
        to the list. If the given `letter` is already in the list, the given
        `frequency` is added to its frequency.

        >>> f = SortedFrequencyList()
        >>> f.add('a', 3)
        >>> f
        ({a: 3})
        >>> f.add('b', 2)
        >>> f
            ({a: 3}, {b: 2})
        >>> f.add('c', 4)
        >>> f
        ({c: 4}, {a: 3}, {b: 2})
        >>> f.add('b', 3)
        >>> f
        ({b: 5}, {c: 4}, {a: 3})
        """

        current = self.head
        found = False
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Frequency(letter, frequency)
        else:
            prev = None
            while current is not None:
                if current.letter == letter:
                    current.frequency = current.frequency + frequency
                    found = True
                prev = current
                current = current.next

                next1 = current.next
                if next1 is None:
                    current = next1

                if current.frequency < next1.frequency:
                    temp = current
                    current = next1
                    next1 = temp
                else:
                    current = next1
                    next1 = current.next.next


            if found is False:
                prev.next = Frequency(letter, frequency)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the lines

```
current = current.next
next1 = current.next
```

what happens if `current.next == None`?

---

I don't know if you are doing this as a Python exercise or because you actually need the functionality; if the latter, there is already a built-in class that does this for you. It's [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (in Python 2.7 or 3.x); if you're using an earlier version then you can make one yourself by subclassing `collections.defaultdict`. It also uses Python dictionaries instead of storing data as key-value pairs.

Example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter()
>>> x['a'] += 2
>>> x['b'] += 3
>>> x['c'] += 1
>>> x
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
```

You can recover the sorted key-value pair representation of your data with

```
x.most_common()
```

Comment: i think thats where the error is occuring but im not sure how to correct this.. should i have a statement like this: if next1 is None: make the current one the last one. how do i implement this?

Comment: @Nirali: work out what you want to do in pseudocode first. Diagrams with squares and arrows help me work out this sort of pointer manipulation. (So e.g. if we have hit the end of the list, so that `current.next == None`, make `current.next == Frequency(letter, frequency)`.)